# Kafka: Who maintains that upto which offset number message is read by a consumer group?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I know that all the messages (or offset) in a Kafka Queue Partition has its offset number and it takes care of the sequence of offsets.
But if I have a Kafka Consumer Group (or single Kafka Consumer) which is reading particularly the  Kafka Topic Partition then how it maintains up to which offset messages are read and who maintains this offset counter?
If the consumer goes down then how a new consumer will start reading the offset from the next unread (or not acknowledged) offset.

Comment: @mike answer is absolutely right for the newer versions of Kafka. For older versions of Kafka(0.8), this information was stored in the Zookeeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information about Consumer Groups is all stored in the internal Kafka topic `__consumer_offsets`. Whenever a new group tries to read data from a topic it checks its offset position in that internal topic which has a deletion policy set to compact. The compaction keeps this topic small.

Kafka comes with a command line tool `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` that helps you understand which information is stored for each consumer group.

More information is given in the [Kafka Documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#impl_offsettracking) on offset tracking.